# Fortran compile error 764 nesting error

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran95

```
    !subroutine No.10: to calculate positive capilary pressure required 

    subroutine Pcow_positive1(sigma_ow,R,alpha,b,teta_ow,Pcow_positive,r1,time)

    implicit none

    !dummy argument declarations 

    double precision,intent(in)::sigma_ow
    double precision,intent(in)::R
    double precision,intent(in)::alpha
    double precision,intent(in)::b
    double precision,intent(in)::teta_ow
    double precision,intent(out)::Pcow_positive
    double precision,intent(out)::r1
    double precision::omega_eff
    double precision::A_eff
    double precision::beta
    double precision::Pcow
    double precision::r2
    double precision::error
    double precision::error1
    double precision::abeta
    integer,intent(out)::time

    !calculate Pcow_positive

       time=0
       r1=R

    700 if (time>1500) then

    goto 950

    else 

    abeta=((b*(sin(alpha)))/(r1))
    if (abeta>1.0) then

    goto 900

    else 

    end if
    beta=asin(abeta)
    time=time+1
    A_eff=(((R**2.0)/(2.0*tan(alpha))))-(((r1)*(b)*(sin(alpha+beta)))/2.0) & 
  +(((((r1)**2)*(beta))/2.0))
    omega_eff=(((((R)*(1.0/(tan(alpha))))-b)*(cos(teta_ow)))+((r1*beta)))
    Pcow=(((sigma_ow)*(omega_eff))/(A_eff))
    r2=(sigma_ow)/(Pcow)

    error=abs(r2-r1)
    error1=abs((sigma_ow/r2)-(sigma_ow/r1))
    if (error<=0.01 .or. error1<=0.01) then

          goto 800

          else 
          r1=r2
          goto 700

          end if

    800   r1=r2
          Pcow_positive=Pcow
          goto 1000

    900   r1=(b*(sin(alpha)))
          Pcow_positive=(sigma_ow)/(r1)
          goto 1000

    950   r1=(sigma_ow)/(0.0005)
          Pcow_positive = 0.0005

    1000  end subroutine Pcow_positive1
```

When I compile the code I get an error message at `end subroutine Pcow_positive1` which I cannot fix. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

> Compile error: error 764 - Nesting error - the block IF construct on line 4079 has not been terminated

line 4079 :

```
700 if (time>1500) then
```

Comment: Indent your code. Do all your `if` statements have corresponding `endif`s?

Comment: You should use indentation to better see the structure of your code. Likely you are missig an `end if` or similar.

Comment: Thank you very much...                                                                          `!calculate Pcow_positive                             time=0 r1=R                                   700 if (time>1500) then                                goto 950                  else          end if`

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with this code. The most immediate is that you are missing an end if. You don't see this because, as noted, you haven't consistently indented your code. Your editor should do this automatically for you and would make spotting this very easy to spot - I cut and paste your code into emacs, auto indented the subprogram and the problem was clear. However where the endif should go was not, and so in what follows I've had to guess where to put it, and as you haven't supplied a complete program it's difficult to test what I have done, but even if I have made a mistake I hope the ideas behind what I have done is clear.

Anyway the next issue is DON'T USE GOTO! There's very rarely any need and it usually leads, as here, to confusing, so called spaghetti code. Instead learn your control structures and use them. A do loop and a few EXITs will tidy this up nicely.

Next all your constants are single precision. Yet all your variables are double precision. As a result your routine will not be as precise as you want. In a double precision code if you see 1.0 with no other qualifier there is almost always something wrong.

So how to fix that. Well Double Precision is so 1980s, so instead learn about kinds, covered in detail any number of times on stackoverflow, or look in your Fortran book (you do have one?) and use them. Anyway putting this all together with the above caveat (and also that I've only spent 5 mins on this, in practice I would tidy further but breakfast is calling) I would write your routine something like

```
    !subroutine No.10: to calculate positive capilary pressure required 

Subroutine Pcow_positive1(sigma_ow,R,alpha,b,teta_ow,Pcow_positive,r1,time)

  Implicit None

  !dummy argument declarations 

  Integer, Parameter :: wp = Selected_real_kind( 12, 70 )

  Real( wp ),Intent(in)::sigma_ow
  Real( wp ),Intent(in)::R
  Real( wp ),Intent(in)::alpha
  Real( wp ),Intent(in)::b
  Real( wp ),Intent(in)::teta_ow
  Real( wp ),Intent(out)::Pcow_positive
  Real( wp ),Intent(out)::r1
  Real( wp )::omega_eff
  Real( wp )::A_eff
  Real( wp )::beta
  Real( wp )::Pcow
  Real( wp )::r2
  Real( wp )::error
  Real( wp )::error1
  Real( wp )::abeta
  Integer,Intent(out)::time

  !calculate Pcow_positive

  time=0
  r1=R


  Do

     If (time>1500) Then


        r1=(sigma_ow)/(0.0005_wp)
        Pcow_positive = 0.0005_wp

        Exit

     End If

     abeta=((b*(Sin(alpha)))/(r1))
     If (abeta>1.0_wp) Then

        r1=(b*(Sin(alpha)))
        Pcow_positive=(sigma_ow)/(r1)
        Exit

     Else 

     End If
     beta=Asin(abeta)
     time=time+1
     A_eff=(((R**2.0_wp)/(2.0_wp*Tan(alpha))))-(((r1)*(b)*(Sin(alpha+beta)))/2.0_wp) & 
          +(((((r1)**2)*(beta))/2.0_wp))
     omega_eff=(((((R)*(1.0_wp/(Tan(alpha))))-b)*(Cos(teta_ow)))+((r1*beta)))
     Pcow=(((sigma_ow)*(omega_eff))/(A_eff))
     r2=(sigma_ow)/(Pcow)

     error=Abs(r2-r1)
     error1=Abs((sigma_ow/r2)-(sigma_ow/r1))
     r1=r2
     If (error<=0.01_wp .Or. error1<=0.01_wp) Then

        Pcow_positive=Pcow
        Exit

     End If

  End Do

End Subroutine Pcow_positive1
```